# Sort records based on "status" field value (running, upcoming, closed) and the records should come based on date in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a requirement to sort the records based on "status" field value( running, upcoming, closed ) order and one more condition is like it should be based on date.

suppose `20-08-2021` and `21-08-2021` is having 7 records like below

| title | date | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 20-08-2021 | 08:00:00 | closed |
| R2 | 20-08-2021 | 12:00:00 | upcoming |
| R3 | 20-08-2021 | 16:00:00 | running |
| R4 | 21-08-2021 | 9:00:00 | running |
| R5 | 21-08-2021 | 15:00:00 | closed |
| R6 | 21-08-2021 | 19:00:00 | upcoming |
| R7 | 21-08-2021 | 14:00:00 | closed |

the results should be like

| title | date | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R3 | 20-08-2021 | 16:00:00 | running |
| R2 | 20-08-2021 | 12:00:00 | upcoming |
| R1 | 20-08-2021 | 08:00:00 | closed |
| R4 | 21-08-2021 | 9:00:00 | running |
| R6 | 21-08-2021 | 19:00:00 | upcoming |
| R7 | 21-08-2021 | 14:00:00 | closed |
| R5 | 21-08-2021 | 15:00:00 | closed |

note: here there is a provision to start any event of future dates so we can have future dates events has running and also R7 should come first as its start time is less than R5.

I have used order by case but is there any effective way to crack it easily and order by case also not solving it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank the rows of each status and then check the value of each status:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY date, time), 
         status = 'running' DESC,
         status = 'upcoming' DESC,
         status = 'closed' DESC;
```

If your version of MySql does not support window functions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
ORDER BY (
           SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM tablename t2 
           WHERE t2.status = t1.status 
             AND CONCAT(t2.date, t2.time) <= CONCAT(t1.date, t1.time)
         ), 
         status = 'running' DESC,
         status = 'upcoming' DESC,
         status = 'closed' DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bb6bf523ba162132ec78b7869413899).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have tried it but its saying dbName.ROW_NUMBER() does not exist

Comment: @Radhika it seems that your version of MySql does not support window functions. See my 2nd query.